# Uninstall broken package

Tags: package-management

Times ago I have installed Linux Mint stuff on my Ubuntu 11.10 (now 12.04). I accidentally removed some files manually (they were under `/usr/share`). Now it is impossible to remove the related deb packages, and synaptic report various errors.

How can remove them bypassing errors? It is possible view the installed files in synaptic and remove them manually, but is tedious... also remain the problem to remove the files entry from the apt database.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Open Terminal and run following command

First Clean Cache.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

remove Unnecessary Packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Update System to latest Packages and Reinstall broken packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Solved. Removed the packages in /var/lib/dpkg/info, and THEN checked in synaptic "ripaire broken packages"

Comment: Avoiding other warnings requires deleting any references to the missing packages in the file /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 1):

To fix or reinstall broken packages run the following in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```